# Equivalence of definitions of Markov Process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, definition, markov-process

I have come across two definitions of Markov processes the first of which is (paraphrased) below (J Sun & TD Lynch, 2008; pg482):

> **Definition 1 (D1)**
>
> A process in which the future probability conditional on the present and past values is equal to the future probability conditional only on the present value. In mathematical notation:
>   $$P(x_0,t_0|x_1,t_1;x_2,t_2;\ldots; x_n t_n)=P(x_0,t_0|x_1,t_1)$$
>   with $t_0\gt t_1 \gt \ldots \gt t_n$.

the other definition (which unfortunately - I don't have an explicit i.e. publicly available reference) is:

> **Definition 2 (D2)**
>
> A process $x(t)$ is a Markov process if future values can be evaluated from current values without any reference to past values.

Take for example the Langevin equation*. My interpretation of this is that we can write:
$$x(t_0)=x(t_1) +\int^{t_1}_{t_0} \eta(t)dt$$
where if the noise $\eta(t)$ was anything but delta correlated it would depend on the previous history and this would then not be a Markov process.

The equivalence between D1 and D2 is intuitively valid. But can it be proved mathematically?

<sub>* Only an example and not the focus of the question - which is about general processes.</sub>

Comment: I might very well be wrong but D2 to me seems like D1 sans the notation. In other words they are identical..

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake My main concern is that D2 is expressed in terms of the solution of a stochastic differential equation whilst D1 in terms of probability. The connection between these two may well be trivial - but until that connection is made I don't think they can be called identical.

Comment: D2 is just the D1. They are same.

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui Playing Devils advocate; I know they are the same (my title even suggests it) - the question is to show that they are the same. The fact that they are to me is not manifest.